# Cloudflare : Traffic -> Health Checks - 403 response code mismatch errors

Tags: cloudflare

I have enabled the Health Checks under Traffic in the CloudFlare and it keep on shows the health check analytics as 403 response code mismatch error. [cloudflare healthchecks error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Lwq.png)

But if i check my site from chrome browser network tab i get only 200 and not getting 403 status code as cloudflare health checks analytics mentions?
my domain name : https://dealsfinders.blog

How do i understand this discrepancy on status codes? I assume something wrong going with my origin server which is not caught when I test my site from a browser client? Why i can't replicate the 403 error on my browser client and caught by Cloudflare?

Comment: Seems like a browser-related issue. Check in other browsers also.

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff i tried with different browser as well and everywhere my site returns status code 200 but my cloudflare healthcheck shows lots of 403. How do i understand this? I assume something wrong going with my origin server which is not caught when i test my site from a browser client?

Comment: 403 means blocked access, hard to say exactly why you get it. Are you sending AJAX?

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff i am using WordPress theme and couple of plugins. Definitely ajax calls will happens. I host my site in cloudflare and using DNS Server and CDN as cloudflare.